# Print each line matching string followed by first line matching string

Tags: bash, awk

I have this:

```
id1
name: Chris
id2
id3
name: John
name: Mary
id4
name: Mike
```

And I need it re-arranged at least like this:

```
id1
name: Chris
id2
name: John
id3
name: Mary
id4
name: Mike
```

But ideally like this:

```
id1 name: Chris
id2 name: John
id3 name: Mary
id4 name: Mike
```

I know this is possible with `awk` but the syntax eludes me. I tried to extrapolate from other more or less similar solutions but without success.

Comment: You should at least post what you've tried, so it looks like you at least did try. And are those what the id's really look like? If so then awk isn't really necessary — just grab the names and add the id's as it iterates.

Comment: Just discard/ignore all the `idX`. Read all `name: *` and prepend them with a running `idX` where `X` is counting number from 1.

Comment: I have an answer, but append what you've tried so far to solve this so that we can have a look on that too.

Comment: Are the numbers after `id` 1,2,3...n in strictly that order? Is, just filter them out.

Comment: Here's a lazy method to do it. `grep ^name: yourfile | cat -n | sed 's/^ */id/'`.

Comment: @alvits : a `grep`, a `cat` and  finally `sed` and you're telling us it's a `lazy method`. ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alternative to awk: this solution `paste`s two process substitutions. The first process returns all the lines starting with `id`, the second process returns all the other lines. Columns are separated by a space (the `-d ' '` option).

```
$ paste -d ' ' <(grep '^id' infile) <(grep -v '^id' infile)
id1 name: Chris
id2 name: John
id3 name: Mary
id4 name: Mike
```

Comment: @mklement0 Thanks!

Comment: Nice touch !! How many ways of solving a single problem.. :-)

Answer (score 2):

```
awk 'BEGIN{
count=0
}
/name/{
count++;printf "id%d %s\n",count,$0
}' your_file_name
```

should do it.

**Output**

```
id1 name: Chris
id2 name: John
id3 name: Mary
id4 name: Mike
```

**Now an elegant one-liner**(Thanks @ed-morton)

```
awk '/name/{print "id"++c,$0}' your_file_name
```

Comment: So long as the `id` labels are 1,2,3, etc but yup - thats it

Comment: You could write that as just `awk '/name/{print "id"++c,$0}' your_file_name`.

Comment: @EdMorton .Thanks , much better but I guess it would be less readable for the op who said `but the syntax eludes me`.

Comment: They have to learn idiomatic awk syntax sometime and IMHO it's best to learn it right away, especially when it's just small examples, rather than seeing how to keep programming in idiomatic C first and then have to unlearn it later. nbd though...

Answer (score 1):

```
$ awk '!/^name:/{id[++a]=$0;next} {print id[++b], $0}' file
id1 name: Chris
id2 name: John
id3 name: Mary
id4 name: Mike
```